# Как добавить строку в динамическую таблицу?

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла проблемка. У меня есть БД и на странице я вывожу одну таблицу. 
При нажатии на кнопку у меня выполняется функция добавления строки в таблицу. 
Но он вставляет эту строку после 2-го элемента, как можно сделать так, чтобы он вставлял её в конце. 
Код JS:

```
function last (array)
          {
              return array[array.length - 1];
          }
      </script>
      <script  type = "text/javascript">
          function addRow(id) {

              var tbody = document.querySelector('#' + id + ' tbody');
              var rows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');


              tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
<tr id = 'tr'>
  <td class="red"><?php $last_id = R::findLast('user'); echo $last_id->id+1 ?></td>
  <td class="green"><input id="pass_login" type="text" value="Логин" ></td>
  <td class="green"><input id="pass_password"  type="text" value="Пароль" ></td>
</tr>
```

Код вывода таблицы:

```
<table id = "myTable" class="table" cellspacing="0" border="1" name = "table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>Логин</th>
              <th>Пароль</th>
          </tr>
    <?php
     $query = R::find( 'user');
foreach( $query as $user ) {
    echo "<tbody><tr> 
    <td name = 'id'  >".$user['id']. "</td><td class='edit_log' name='login' id='login'>" .$user['login']."</td><td class='edit_pas' name='pas' id='pas'>".$user['password']. "</td></tr></tbody>";


}
    ?>
      </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Всо не стоит, я нашёл у себя глупейшую ошибку. 
Я в цикле каждую строку заносил в отдельный "
tbody"